# What's the use of creating another CKeditor profile

Tags: wysiwyg

CKeditor comes standard with 2 profiles: one for filtered html, and one for full html. Now I added a third one, but whats the use?

There are only 2 text format.. So why is it possible to create a third ckeditor profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's also possible to create as many/few text formats as you want...

If you had installed Drupal using a non-standard profile, you might not even have `full_html` and `filtered_html` as text formats, and the CKeditor profiles would be different.

If you don't know why you need to add one...don't add one :)

Comment: aah oke, this also solves my next question. I wanted to link my ckeditor to a certain content type. So what I have to do is set a custom text format for that content type, and then create a profile for that text format. Thx! I'm new and still learning dru to the pal